# Can't add records after the 8th ms-access related table

Tags: ms-access

I am sorry, to all of you who have answered, for my bad English and lack of information.

I am working on a project that needs to include the entire structure of the UDC - Universal Decimal Classification which is a bibliographic classification system.

I need 10 or 11 related tables.

Tbl1 relates (one-to-many) Tbl2; Tbl2 relates (one-to-many) Tbl3; Tbl3 relates (one-to-many) Tbl4;Tbl4 relates (one-to-many) Tbl5; Tbl5 relates (one-to-many) Tbl6; (...) to the last table.

I've done the relations without difficulties ... the problem arises in filling the tables, in concrete, after the eighth table. I can not find the "+" sign, in table mode, to create new record in the ninth table.

Screenshot:

[image: here is a print screen of my problem]

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Are you trying use a single query that includes all these tables as a data entry interface? That is not conventional data entry design. This is not really a suitable question for this forum. Hardly suitable for any forum. Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @June7 "Hardly suitable for any forum?"  Even if the question could be formatted better with more detail, since when does less-than-ideal design disqualify someone from asking a question?  Perfectly normalized tables and perfectly efficient design are *not* a requirement for asking questions.  And even if it turns out that the question is not well received here does not mean there is no forum anywhere that the person can't get help or advise.

Comment: @Amilcar  You can improve your question with details to make it more suitable for Stack Overflow.  Exactly what error are you getting?  What is the context:  Are you using an Access form, or trying to update the data using VBA code?  Show the code and learn how to properly format it--in your case, perhaps just the SQL query for your form?  You can edit your question to include these details.

Comment: Sorry for bad wording. Just trying to make point we need info, as would be the case at any forum. And since this appears to be db design issue, not coding, Stackoverflow may not have been ideal forum to use. But since I have helped with many non-code issues here, open to do so here if can get enough info.

Comment: Interesting problem, you probably have stumbled upon a limitation of Access datasheet view. But this isn't really the intended way to enter data, is it? I would assume that if you build forms for data entry, and insert the proper foreign keys, that you can insert data into Table9 just fine.

Comment: Additional note: from [Access 2016 specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2016-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c): *(Max.) Number of levels of nested forms or reports: 7* -- This may or may not be related. Just be aware that you can't do 10 levels deep of subforms...

Comment: Thank you, Andre, for your response and patience.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for responding. I was initially surprised since you are usually very welcoming and helpful.  I did some research and found that perhaps the (Stack Exchange) Data Administrators website would be most appropriate for this question.  In particular, [this meta question and answer](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-ms-access-on-topic) dispelled my initial misgivings about MS Access question on that site.  A search of the site also shows related question with [ms-access] tags.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think this is exactly the issue:

**[Access 2016 specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2016-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c) -> Form and Report**

```
Number of levels of nested forms or reports   7
```

You have the base table `Table1`, and then 7 levels of nested sub-tables (`Table2 .. Table8`), and then Access doesn't provide further nesting.

Editing data directly in so deeply nested table would be impractical anyways. You'll need forms to navigate the levels and parents, and enter data. Breadcrumbs navigation is probably a good idea.

Actually, I would use a single main form where you switch the recordsource depending on the current level.

Note: for ad-hoc data entry at the deepest levels, just open e.g. `Table7` directly, and enter the foreign keys to `Table6` manually.

Comment: Thank you all for the support.